# Cuál es la expresión regular que permita validar un número de 0 hasta 3 dígitos?

Tags: javascript, regex

Por ejemplo quiero validar un campo de número que contenga desde 0 al 150.
Entonces validaría números como 2, 15, 124 y no el 160, 2301.
Una opción sería esta `^\d{5}$` pero no valida que sea de un valor específico a otro.

Comment: Podrías editar por favor y mostrarnos que llevas hecho al momento?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806298/12511801

Comment: No considero que una regex para esto sea lo más adecuado o necesario

Comment: Incluso si buscas comprobar varios a la vez ocupa un ciclo que los genere, por dentro un condicional y debería alcanzar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es necesaria una regex, pero si hubiera que hacerla igual, podría ser algo como esto: `^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)$` en donde hacemos un `OR` si tiene una dos o tres cifras.

```js
function validar(numero){
    return /^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)$/.test(numero);
}

console.log(validar(0));
console.log(validar(9));
console.log(validar(15));
console.log(validar(124));
console.log(validar(150));
console.log(validar(151));
console.log(validar(2301));
```

Answer (score 6):

Si no tienes una necesidad específica de usar una Expresión Regular, con simple Javascript debería bastar:

```js
var validar = a => !isNaN(a) && a >= 0 && a <= 150;

console.log(validar(2));
console.log(validar(15));
console.log(validar(124));
console.log(validar(160));
console.log(validar(2301));
```